# Get the version from child in the parent POM in Maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, maven-shade-plugin

I have a parent pom A with children pom B, C and D. In the B, C and D, I have dependencies with the same type.

ie Parent Pom

```
<artifactID>blah</artifactID>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>B</module>
        <module>C</module>
        <module>D</module>
    </modules>
```

I have a parent pom A with children pom B, C and D. In the B, C and D, I have dependencies with the same type.

ie Parent Pom

```
<artifactID>blah</artifactID>
<modules>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
    <module>D</module>
</modules>
```

child Pom

```
<build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                  <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                      <manifestEntries>
                        <Child1Version>${project.version}</Child1Version> <!-- How to do this generic for any child pom ???? -->
                      </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                  </transformers>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My question I want to change parent pom package pom to jar and get all build child and put it in parent pom and get child version to parent pom. for each child. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Parents POM need to have the packaging `pom`. You cannot have a parent POM with packaging `jar`.